# Is there a better way to create Splash/ Loading screen in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, coding-style, splash-screen

Creating an automated Tkinter Gui dashboard and going to deploy it using pyinstaller(.exe)
The application takes a lot of time to load. So I decided to add a loading screen / splash screen.
I was learning about it on youtube and some blogs. All of them created a dummy main application

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from PIL import ImageTk, Image 
import time

w=Tk()

width_of_window = 500
height_of_window = 500
screen_width = w.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = w.winfo_screenheight()
x_coordinate = (screen_width/2)-(width_of_window/2)
y_coordinate = (screen_height/2)-(height_of_window/2)
w.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" %(width_of_window,height_of_window,x_coordinate,y_coordinate))
#w.configure(bg='#ED1B76')
w.overrideredirect(1) #for hiding titlebar

#new window to open
def new_win():
    q=Tk()
    q.title('main window')
    q.mainloop()
```

I have a very big application, So Do I really have to put it in a function definition or is there a better way of doing it? It does work but I find it odd to put such a big code in a function.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the better way is to only create a single instance of `Tk`.

One way is to create a class based on a frame for your splash screen, and another class for your main application. Add the frame for the splash screen to the root window and then construct the frame for the main app. When you're ready to switch, remove the splash screen frame and add the frame for the main app.

Alternatively, use `Toplevel` for the splash screen and withdraw the root window until you're ready to display it. Then, hide or destroy the instance of `Toplevel` and show the root window.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Do you have a practical reference link? If not, still thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

in `new_win` function

- In line 20, add `w.destroy()`
- in line 23, add geometry layout.
- in line 25, add `after` out the function.

Scrippet, using same script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
 
import time

w=Tk()

width_of_window = 500
height_of_window = 500
screen_width = w.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = w.winfo_screenheight()
x_coordinate = (screen_width/2)-(width_of_window/2)
y_coordinate = (screen_height/2)-(height_of_window/2)
w.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" %(width_of_window,height_of_window,x_coordinate,y_coordinate))
#w.configure(bg='#ED1B76')
w.overrideredirect(1) #for hiding titlebar

#new window to open
def new_win():
    w.destroy()
    q=Tk()
    q.title('main window')
    q.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" %(width_of_window,height_of_window,x_coordinate,y_coordinate))

w.after(3000, new_win)    
w.mainloop()
```